# Calling addEVentListener and removeEventListener in two different modules

Tags: javascript, electron

This document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) mentions that in order to remove an `eventListener`, the handler function must be exactly the same.

I have two modules:
`module1.js`

```
const module2 =require('./module2');
let myButton = document.getElementById("testButton")
myButton.addEventListener("click", module2.clickHandler.bind(null, myButton.value))
```

Then, in `module2.js`

```
const clickHandler = (buttonValue) => {
 ...do something...
}

const unrelatedHandler = (someVar) => {
   let myButton = document.getElementById("testButton")
   myButton.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler.bind(null, myButton.value))
   ...do the rest of the intended tasks...
}
```

In `module2`, I have `unrelatedHandler` which is intended to remove the event listener of `myButton`. However, calling the `removeEVentListener` as above does not remove it at all. This is in an Electron app and due to its framework, `module1.js` is executed immediately at startup. Functions in `module2.js` could be executed later after startup.

How do I call `removeEventListener` with the same handler from two different modules? Thanks.
(module1.js is the renderer of an Electron app, by the way).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that calling **.bind** creates a new function; that means that when you call **removeEventListener** you are passing a new function.

You should store the reference to the first bind call:

```
const myBtnFunc = module2.clickHandler.bind(null, button.value);
myButton.addEventListener("click", myBtnFunc);
```

and call the **removeEventListener** with the same reference

```
myButton.removeEventListener("click", myBtnFunc))
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind